# Context Menu in NSBrowser

Tags: cocoa, nsbrowser

When right-clicking on an item in an `NSBrowser` view the selection won't change. Instead the item clicked on gets a frame and a context menu is opened. Selected item and right-clicked item are two different things.

In Finder (browser view), the operations in the context menu operate on the item the user right-clicks on, which is what I expect. If I do the same with a custom `NSBrowser` control, the operations are applied to the selected item instead.

I have attached an empty `NSMenu` to `NSBrowser.menu` to get the services menu. There  are `NSBrowser`'s `clickedRow`/`clickedColumn` properties which yield valid values when queried from `[NSMenuDelegate menuWillOpen]`, but this does not help me with the system-generated Services menu items.

How can I make the context menu operate on the right-clicked item?

**EDIT 2017-10-29**

I have subclassed NSBrowser for drag&drop support. This is how the context menu is added. It is an empty `NSMenu`, the Services menu is added automatically.

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    NSMenu *m = [[[NSMenu alloc] init] autorelease];
    m.delegate = self;
    self.menu = m;
}
```

Comment: How do you add the services to the menu? `NSBrowser` doesn't support any services. And how do you communicate with the service?

Comment: It adds services in my case, see my edit.

Comment: I found the problem: I have implemented the `validRequestorForSendType:returnType` and `writeSelectionToPasteboard:types` methods. These methods get called when I right-click on an item. In these methods I query `[self selectedCell]`. But I have to query `[self.clickedColumn]` and `[self.clickedRow]`and use these values if they return positive values.